# moodle getting values out of database

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I stored several values in new fields of my plugin in the settings.php
However now I'm trying to put those values that I made onscreen, and I couldn't find a way to do that in moodle. Is there a way to do this in Moodle?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you named the setting in settings.php something like 'PLUGINNAME/SETTINGNAME' (e.g. in the enrol_manual core plugin has a setting called 'enrol_manual/expiredaction'), then you can retrieve a single setting via:

```
$value = get_config('PLUGINNAME', 'SETTINGNAME');
$value = get_config('enrol_maual', 'expiredaction'); // For example.
```

If you want all the settings for a given plugin, then you can call:

```
$values = get_config('PLUGINNAME');
$values = get_config('enrol_manual'); // For example.
```

If, however, you've followed the bad practice of several of the settings for older core plugins, and the setting is called something like 'MYPLUGIN_SETTINGNAME', then you can retrieve the setting by calling:

```
$value = get_config('core', 'PLUGINNAME_SETTINGNAME');
$value = get_config('core', 'forum_displaymode'); // For example.
```

OR

```
global $CFG;
$value = $CFG->PLUGINNAME_SETTINGNAME;
$value = $CFG->forum_displaymode; // For example.
```

Naming settings without the '/' is bad, as it means the settings are loaded into the main $CFG global, which is already pretty bloated. Organising them into plugins also means all the plugin settings can be loaded as a simple object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I phrased my question wrong. I'm trying to get those values out of my database, not strings from a seperate file.

Comment: get_config retrieves the values from the database (get_string is used to retrieve strings from a file).